# Help somebody check how well they have memorized a piece of text

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-request

Is there a verb for somebody to use when they want to ask someone to help them check how well they have memorized a piece of text such as a poem or a speech? Also, is there a descriptive term or an idiomatic phrase for this process?

*Scenario:*
You are approaching Dylan asking if he could listen to you as you recite a poem and correct or prompt you when you get stuck. If they agree you give them the poem so they can follow your recitation.

Comment: You can ask, "Can you quiz me on this poem have to memorize?"  Or since that may imply more 'asking random questions', "Can you check me on this poem I have to memorize?"

Answer (score 2):

You could say: ***Would you help me go over/rehearse a poem I memorized?***

And then you may want to add ***cue me/coach me as I recite*** while handing them the book.

Answer (score 2):

In the theatre we call this process of working through the text focusing only on speaking the dialogue correctly ***running lines***. You can of course run your lines with the other actors (this is a ***line rehearsal***), and most actors spend hours preparing for rehearsals running their lines by themselves; but it's more effective to have somebody else "on book" to cue, prompt and correct you. To request this help you'd say something like

> Could you run lines with me?

And my wife frequently recalls her labor coaching one actor who had great difficulty with memorization:

> I spent hours running lines with N___.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a bit of religiosity you could use the word catechize (origin: teach orally, instruct by word of mouth).  The word is a little obscure but the Catholic 'catechism' derives from it.